# Ways to find a UMP test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, inference, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

I'm studying for my final exams and the subject of proof will basically test hypotheses, I will try to summarize here my doubts.

For found the UMP test the ways are

> 1) Use Neyman–Pearson lemma where the test is of the type
>   $$H_0:\theta=\theta_0\space vs \space H_1:\theta=\theta_1$$ and the
>   pdf is $f(x|\theta)$ with critical region $R$ is $x\in R$ if
>   $\frac{f(x|\theta_1)}{f(x|\theta_0)}>k$ and $x\in R^c$ if
>   $\frac{f(x|\theta_1)}{f(x|\theta_0)}<k$ for any $k\geq 0$ and
>   $\alpha=P_{\theta_0}(X\in R)$
>
> 2)If $T$ is a sufficient statistic and the family of pdf's of $T$ have
>   monotone likelihood-ratio then you can apply Karlin-Rubin theorem for
>   test the hypotheses $$H_0:\theta\leq \theta_0\space vs\space
> > H_1:\theta>\theta_0$$ where the test is reject $H_0\Leftrightarrow
> > T>t_0$ and $\alpha=P_{\theta_0}(T>t_0)$

I know that Neyman-Pearson lemma can only be applied to simple hypothesis, but there is a "trick" to apply Neyman-Pearson lemma, where you can change the simple hyphotesis
$$H_0:\theta=\theta_0\space vs\space H_1:\theta=\theta_1$$
to $$H_0':\theta=\theta_0\space vs \space H_1':\theta=\theta_1, \space\theta_1>\theta_0$$
$$H_0':\theta=\theta_0\space vs \space H_1':\theta=\theta_1, \space\theta_1<\theta_0$$
$$H_0':\theta=\theta_0\space vs \space H_1':\theta=\theta_1, \space\theta_1\neq\theta_0$$

Let's take an example for me to try to clarify what I mean by trick. Suppose I want a UMP test $$H_0:\theta=5\space vs\space H_1:\theta>5$$
I can not apply directly the Neyman-Pearson lemma in this case, then I did
$$H_0:\theta=5\space vs\space H_1:\theta=\theta_1\space,\space \theta_1>5$$

these changes implies something in the critical region? In the size of test?

I can do this kind of manipulation in the null hypothesis?

Is there any other way to find a UMP test?

Could someone explain me especially how to get a UMP test for a density that does not belong to the exponential family?

Comment: "Can someone also explain me the difference between the likelihood ratio test and apply the Neyman–Pearson lemma?" - I don't understand what you're asking. The N-P Lemma says the LRT is UMP for two simple hypotheses.

Comment: @Scortchi I had seen the relationship, but as my book does not say anything explicitly was in doubt. Is there any other way to find a UMP test?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify what you were asking there. Another thing I want to clarify after your edit is exactly what these "tricks" are. (I was also going to point out that monotone likelihood ratios *can* be found outside the exponential family, but you must've realized that.)

Comment: @Scortchi My main question is how to find UMP tests for composite hypotheses?I edited it to try to explain what is the trick.

Comment: So the trick's that the UMP test for $H_0:\theta=5$ vs $H_1:\theta>5$ is the same as the UMP test for, say, $H_0:\theta=5$ vs $H_1:\theta=6$, which you know from the N-P lemma is the LRT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Part & parcel of being a *uniformly* most powerful test for $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ vs $H_1:\theta>\theta_0$ is being most powerful for $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ vs $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$ for whichever $\theta_1>\theta$ you choose. So the tests are exactly the same. (But there isn't always a UMP test for one-sided alternative hypotheses. Testing hypotheses about the location parameter of a Cauchy with known scale is a standard example.)

(2) The Karlin-Rubin theorem tells you that there is a UMP test for a one-sided alternative hypothesis, & how to form it, when the density (or mass) function of the sufficient statistic has a monotone likelihood ratio. There's no caveat that its distribution must belong to an exponential family; rather if it does belong to the (full) exponential family it will have monotone likelihood ratio. The hypergeometric distribution provides an example of a test statistic whose distribution does not belong to the exponential family & yet whose mass function has a monotone likelihood ratio.

(3) I don't know of *general* methods for finding UMP tests other than those you've described. As noted above, they don't always exist; then restricting your search to UMP unbiased tests or locally most powerful tests might be of interest, as might showing that a test under consideration is admissible (i.e. there's no other test with greater power under all versions of the alternative).

Comment: "if it does belong to the exponential family it will have monotone likelihood ratio" I think you need "full regular" exponential family. And Pfanzagl proved that if there is a UMP test  for one-sided test regardless of sample size, then it must be a 1-dim exponential family, which is a well-known result in "Pfanzagl, Johann. "A characterization of the one parameter exponential family by existence of uniformly most powerful tests." Sankhyā: The Indian Journal of Statistics, Series A (1968): 147-156."

Comment: @Henry.L: Thanks, & sorry for forgetting to reply. The paper went over my head rather; but I do understand that (almost) only one-parameter full exponential families will have a scalar sufficient statistic for i.i.d. samples regardless of sample size, & that their likelihood ratio is a monotone function of this parameter. The exception is of course families whose parameter determines the support - for e.g. a uniform distributions on 0 to $\theta$ the sample maximum is sufficient & the likelihood ratio monotone.  ...

Comment: ... More importantly perhaps, we're often looking for U.M.P. similar or U.M.P. invariant tests. The one-sample *t*-test is a familiar example: the sample of $n$ is from a 2-dim exponential family with a 2-dim sufficient statistic yet what matters is the sample of 1 from a 1-dim non-exponential family (the non-central *t*-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom) with a 1-dim sufficient statistic & monotone likelihood ratio. Fisher's Exact Test is another one.

Comment: I have had thought of monotonic likelihood ratio property  (MLR) at that point, but have difficulty in how I thought my comment will help (after 7 years!) But really thanks for the reply!