# What is the general methodology for constructing a UMP test for a simple hypothesis versus a composite one?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, neyman-pearson-lemma

I think I understand the Neyman-Pearson lemma, but I'm really struggling to understand the reasoning with which it's used as a building block to build tests for composite hypotheses.

Take [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/308) worked example, say. At the end, they say that "the" critical region C defines a UMP test, but from what I can tell, they've got a whole family of regions C, one for each alternative hypothesis $\mu_\alpha$. So you still can't say you've found a single test which is UMP for the entrire alternative hypothesis $\mu_\alpha > 10.

Comment: There's just one critical region specified there: $C=\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n):\bar{x} \geq k^*\}$. The critical value $k^*$ is defined solely by considering the simple null hypothesis.

Comment: @Scortchi Let me get this straight. So for each $\mu$, and each $k$, we can find the region $C(\mu, k)$ such that $L(10)/L(\mu)<k$. That region depends on both $\mu$ and $k$. Now we ask: which value of $k$ will give that region a fixed probability $\alpha$? That value of $k$ will be different for each $\mu$, call it $k(\mu)$. And incredibly, $C(\mu, k(\mu))$ is constant as a function of $\mu$, *even though $k$ might not be*! Does that witchcraft always happen, or did we just get lucky because of algebraic properties of the Gaussian distribution?

Comment: We got lucky - the Gaussian distribution has the monotone likelihood ratio property.

Comment: @Scortchi So when that property isn't satisfied, is finding a UMP test just not possible? What if you apply Neyman-Pearson to find an optimal region for each alternative hypothesis $\theta\in\Theta_1$, and find that they're all different for each $\theta$? Is the conclusion that there doesn't exist a UMP test for the composite alternative hypothesis $\Theta_1$?

Comment: That's right. Try that with e.g. tests on the location parameter of a Cauchy (with known scale) based on a single observation.

Comment: For testing $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ against $H_1:\theta \in \Theta_1\subset \Theta-\{\theta_0\}$, suppose one can derive an MP test using NP lemma by expressing the alternative as $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$ where $\theta_1$ is any member of $\Theta_1$. If this test is independent of $\theta_1$, then it is also UMP by definition; if it depends on $\theta_1$, then no UMP test exists. And as already mentioned, if the population distribution has the MLR property then a UMP test is found using Karlin-Rubin theorem. These two methods are discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/158698/119261).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ways to find a UMP test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158698/ways-to-find-a-ump-test)